# How to create floating action button transforming into a single sheet of material

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to see if any in-build animation exist on the design library to create floating action button transforming into single material sheet like shown in the material design image

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B8v7jImPsDi-TjBicTdvQjg4M1E/components-buttons-fab-transition_card_02.webm

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436242/how-to-implement-menu-display-on-extended-floating-action-button-click-android/62438888#62438888

Answer (score 2):

Use `MaterialContainerTransform` from Material Components:

```
 private fun toggleFabMenu() {
        val views = listOf<View>(fab, menuView).sortedBy { !it.isVisible }

        val shareMenuTransform = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            startView = views.first()
            endView = views.last()           
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            duration = 500
                      
        }
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, shareMenuTransform)
        views.first().isVisible = false
        views.last().isVisible = true
    }
```

[image]

See docs for more details: https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion

Comment: Omg! that was such a quick reply to this question! I am stunned! He mush be in urgent need to this answer, you saved his lot of time! How you managed give an answer so fast sir? Can you tell me this technique please.

Comment: @CodeDexter sure. The main motivation is upvotes amount on this question. So i decided my knowledge may be useful for lot of devs. Now and in the future. That is how stackoverflow community works. Welcome

Comment: Oh I see! 4 years is a huge gap, but it will certainly help a lot of new devs, and sorry for my sarcastic tone! I am flattered that you replied so humbly! Can you help me with this question I am stuck at handling touch events! Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023789/handle-touch-event-on-both-segments-of-the-screen-simultaneously

Comment: how to add scrim?