# Floating Action Button Morph Fill in Form

Tags: java, android, user-interface, floating-action-button

I´m new in programming. I have a school project which we have to programm an App and my part is to programm the UI.

I used the standard Action Bar Theme from Android Studio and have that floating action button in the right lower corner.

I want to replace the snackbar and do the same as you can see in this picture: [FAB with fill in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlYrl.png)

How can I do this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


           //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
             //      .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want to position your `FAB` as it is in that picture?

Comment: No if I press the fab the fill in form should pop up, with 2 textfields and a button. just a little bit like it is in the picture

Comment: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions in the middle of the side; The floating action button can transform into a single sheet of material which contains all the actions. that would work as well

Comment: This is almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093198/how-to-create-floating-action-button-transforming-into-a-single-sheet-of-materia