# Handle Touch Event on both segments of the screen simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-touch-event

So I have a touch event and it handles `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` one by one. For example if I click on the left half of the screen `ACTION_DOWN` works but not `ACTION_UP` and same for the right side of the screen. i want to handle both of them simultaneously. If I click on left side and right side at the same time both the event should perform. Can anyone please help me on this.
My code is

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //if user press the screen
            if (event.getX() < screenX / 2f) {
                flight.isGoingUp = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            flight.isGoingUp = false;
            if (event.getX() > screenX / 2f) {
                flight.toShoot++;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit 1**
The screen is split into two half. The left side of the screen is used for `flight.isGoingUp = true;` and when we release the left side or tap the right helg of the screen `flight.isGoingUp = false;` and `if (event.getX() > screenX / 2f) { flight.toShoot++; }` I want ot do such a code that both of them are handled at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the docs to handle multi touch gestures.

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi#java

Here is a very simple example to handle multitouch based on google docs.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    System.out.println("The finger # " + index + " is " + getAction(action));
    return true;
}

public static String getAction(int action) {
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: return "Down";
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: return "Move";
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: return "Pointer Down";
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: return "Up";
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: return "Pointer Up";
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: return "Outside";
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: return "Cancel";
        default: return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I already read that document but i;m not getting how to do it!

Comment: First See my question. The screen is split into two half. The left side of the screen is used for `flight.isGoingUp = true;` and when we release the left side or tap the right helg of the screen `flight.isGoingUp = false;` and `if (event.getX() > screenX / 2f) {
                flight.toShoot++;
            }` I want ot do such a code that both of them are handled at the same time.

Comment: You can get the x and y position of the point and validates with your requirements, if the x and y position is located in the left screen then do this, if is located on the right position do that.